Encrypt my own message and its giving a different message
So I'm trying to encrypt my own message but its coming out in symbols instead of letters.
Here is my code below
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

    s0, s1 = 1, 0
    t0, t1 = 0, 1

    while b != 0:
        q = a // b
        a, b = b, a % b
        s0, s1 = s1, s0 - q * s1
        t0, t1 = t1, t0 - q * t1

    return a, (s0, t0)



Why don't you use the fixed code from your old question, but delete it instead? This code works, i.e. it encrypts and decrypts the data correctly: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/16XZ! And to find the bug in the new code, you only need to compare the new code with the old code: This way you can easily find the cause of your issue, it is the missing if a < b: a, b = b, a block in EEA(): https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/16Yv.

You can of course also apply the solution from the answer (which performs the determination of the modular mult. inverse directly), but I assume that the purpose of this exercise is to implement the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, whose implementation is the actual cause of your problem.

You're not computing the private key correctly.  The private key has to be the inverse of the public key, modulo the totient.
Replace this:
    d = t % phi_n
    return d

with this:
    return pow(e,-1,phi_n)

Output:
Public Key (n, e): (3233, 7)
Private Key (n, d): (3233, 1783)
Encoded message: [1298, 3052, 1818, 1762, 2774, 567, 1297, 96, 3071, 1797, 96, 3183, 863, 3071, 1797, 2774, 863, 3183, 1297, 1877, 2872, 2774, 731, 3183, 1297, 2774, 3052, 1818, 1794, 3071, 2774, 3020, 576, 2774, 731, 3183, 1297, 2774, 3052, 1818, 2872, 2774, 1762, 3052, 3071, 2774, 24, 3052, 3183, 3020, 24, 3071, 2774, 3183, 576, 2774, 3183, 1544, 3071, 2080]
Decoded message: What superpower would you have if you had the choice of one?


Thanks for the update, i figured it out after a couple of hours.
